# About the different forms of asking a question

Tags: questions, registre

What does “registre élevé”, “registre courant” and “registre familier” mean?
This is because from the book I am studying, the structure of the question changes — *Avez-vous des timbres ?*, *Est-ce que vous avez des timbres ?* and *Vous avez des timbres ?*, respectively.

Comment: It's not « registre élève », it's « registre élevé » (high). So it's the same than « registre soutenu ».

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three "registres" which are level languages. These levels depends of your public.
 "registre élevé/soutenu", "registre courant/normal" and "registre familier".

See [Wiki for more information](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registres_de_langue_en_fran%C3%A7ais)

## Registre Elevé / Soutenu

Use in literary circles or some speeches and publications, or with a interlocutor to whom it attaches importance.

## Registre courant/ Normal

Simple vocabulary, including all single complex sentence. Grammar and syntax are met.

## Registre Familier

The familiar level that is used among friends and family. Reserved for oral. Vocabulary often relaxed, sometimes vulgar or rude